# Why do I have four CPUs listed in /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: cpu, proc

When I bought my Lenovo Thinkpad 520, it had Windows installed. I promptly cleaned that out and installed Fedora 16.  I recently visited the `/proc/cpuinfo` and, much to my surprise, discovered that it has four CPUs listed (0-3).  I do not remember asking for extra CPUs when I got it, believeing I was getting only a single processor.  Could this be a mistake in the `cpuinfo` file?

Comment: Most likely you have a (single) i5 processor: two cores + hyperthreading = 4 CPUs

Comment: Flag for SuperUser?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Er. Why?

Comment: @Michael it's not really Unix specific. Sure, the program is, but this could also affect a Windows system if the program was poorly coded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the T520's specs](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/system_data/t520_tech_specs.pdf):

> Intel® Core™ i5-2520M processor (dual-core, 2.50GHz, 3MB Cache),

The [i5-2520M has](http://ark.intel.com/products/52229/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz) 2 cores + hyper threading, for a total of 4 cores seen by the system.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have one processor with two cores and hyper threading technology. The hyper threading doubles the reported CPUs.

```
2 cores + hyper threading = 4 reported CPUs
```